# How could locate the problematic line in the source code (the same key exception)

Tags: reactjs

I know how to solve this exception.

The thing is.The warning doesn't mention the exception happened at which line / which file.
Anyway to locate the accurate root cause?

```
    Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, ``. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
        in div (created by Component)
        in div (created by Component)
        in Component (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in App (created by Connect(App))
        in Connect(App)
        in Provider
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703160/react-warning-flattenchildren-encountered-two-children-with-the-same-key

Comment: @sumit this is not my question. how could you locate the source code at which line?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a question, though I think the problem is with the key, make sure it is unique(can be id or any unique value inside your data) when rendering the same component multiple times most likely inside an iteration.e.g

```
data.map((val) => <Component key={val.id} />)
```