# Most efficient way of rendering JSX elements when iterating on array of data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

I have an array which contains objects. I am creating a map of this array to renders the names with a `span` component.

```
let data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];
```

I have been using the below two different functionalities to iterate on that array of objects, and using map to render JSX elements.

### Functionality1:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    let data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];
    const items = data.map((key, i) => {
      return <span key={key.id}>{key.name}</span>;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

### Functionality2:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    let data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];
    let rows = [];
    data.map((key, i) => {
      rows.push(<span key={key.id}>{key.name}</span>);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

I known to the above two different ways of using `map` and rendering JSX elements. Is there any other ways of doing the same, apart from these two? If so, which is recommended?

Comment: "Functionality2" creates an Array when `.map` is called that is never used. Switch to `data.forEach` so no unnecessary Array is created.

Comment: but that is only when assigned to a reference right? like const array = data.map( correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No, the Array is created regardless of whether you assign it to a variable. In your code above, the Array is created and then immediately eligible for garbage collection because no references point to it. If you switch to [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), no extra Array is created.

Comment: OK understood. Thanks. Can you also help me with other ways of rendering jsx elements when we render them in iteration. Apart from what I mentioned and others mentioned below

Comment: Put together a quick [JsPerf](https://jsperf.com/rendering-react-component-array) comparison of your two approaches, as well as some variants. Functionnality1 is your best bet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mostly, I follow this rule:

Create a component which renders the items

```
// in some file
export const RenderItems = ({data}) => {
  return data && data.map((d, i) => <span key={d.id}>{d.name}</span>) || null
}
```

Hook the RenderItems

```
import { RenderItems } from 'some-file'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    // you may also define data here instead of getting data from props
    const { data } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <RenderItems data={data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Attach the data in the component

```
const data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}]
<App data={data} />
```

Following this rule will not impact on performance even with your second example of code ie. pushing items in an array and rendering the items. Because, you're not directly working inside the render hook. Always take care that render hook wouldn't implement any logic inside it directly.

---

Further, I wouldn't create `id` just for using key:

```
const data = [{"name": "Hi"}, {"name": "Hello"}]
//... and when using index as key
.map((d, i) => <span key={'item-'+i}>
// or,
.map((d, i) => <span key={'item-'+i+'-'+d.name}>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220453/2138752) why I follow this syntax while using index as key.

---

## Update:

If you want to avoid unnecessary html tags being used, you can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
export const RenderItems = ({data}) => {
  return data && 
    data.map(
      (d, i) => <React.Fragment key={d.id}>{d.name}</React.Fragment>
    ) || null
}
// and when rendering, you just return the component
return <RenderItems data={data} />
```

**Note:**

1. You can use `<></>` as an alias for `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` only if you don't have any additional property. Since we're using key property on it, not using it.
2. Take a look at [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax) to make support for short notation of `React.Fragment`.

Example using `<></>`:

```
<>{d.name}</>
```

This will be rendered `d.name`'s value in html without any tag. This is considered best when we specifically transform our existing design to react application. Or, there might be other cases. Like, we are going to display a definition list:

```
<dl>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt></dd>
</dl>
```

And we don't want to attach unnecessary html tag, then using Fragment will make our life easier:

Example:

```
<>
  <dt>{d.term}</dt>
  <dd>{d.definition}</dd>
</>
```

The most important case will be for rendering `td` element in `tr` (a TR component). If we don't, then we're breaking the rule of HTML. The component will not be rendered properly. In react, it will throw you an error.

## Update2:

Also, if you have [long list of props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271398/how-do-i-compose-a-better-react-list-container-component) like below:

```
const {
  items,
  id,
  imdbID,
  title,
  poster,
  getMovieInfo,
  addToFavorites,
  isOpen,
  toggleModal,
  closeModal,
  modalData,
} = props
```

You may consider destructuring like:

```
const { items, ...other } = props
// and in your component you can use like:
<div modalData={other.modalData}>
```

But, personally I prefer using first example code. It's because while developing I won't need to look back to other component or look for the console each and every time. In the given example there's key like `modalData={}` so we easily maintain `modalData={other.modalData}`. But what if it is needed to code like `<div>{modalData}</div>`? Then, you may also agree with my preference.

Comment: Thank you. I never tried like this before seeing it for the first time.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: An index is appropriate to be used as a key here but is considered bad practice in general. The answer doesn't mention that.

Comment: @estus when used with some constant value it's not considered bad.

Answer (score 12):

I would do this

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}];

export default class App extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(({ id, name }) => <span key={id}>{name}</span>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, your `data` is not reinstantiated on every render, and you don't have to garbage collect any unnecessary variable declarations.

Comment: Upvoted. I would add that if you want to avoid wrapping the `<span>` elements in a `<div>` you can use React Fragments: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 8):

The first way is better.

1. `Array.prototype.map` creates an array behind the scenes and returns it after applying the modification on each element. **Functionality-1** creates two arrays, while **Functionality-2** creates three.
2. **Functionality-1** reads better. It's how React code usually being written. For a simple element like this, I'd save the **const definition** for items and put the map statement in the **JSX** to be returned **directly**.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, `for` or `while` statement is the most efficient way to iterate an array. The way a small array is processed in non-critical place can be considered microoptimisation.

The use of `map` is idiomatic in React components because it's fast enough and can return a value as a part of an expression.

While this is an antipattern:

```
let rows = [];
data.map((key, i) => {
  rows.push(<span key={key.id}>{key.name}</span>);
});
```

`map` is supposed to map array elements to other values (hence the name), not to iterate an array instead of `forEach` or other loop. This problem can be tracked with ESLint [`array-callback-return`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return) rule.

The component is stateless and doesn't need to be `Component` class. It can be functional component or `PureComponent` class. Since `data` is constant, it doesn't need to be assigned on each render:

```
const data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];

const App = props => <div>
  {data.map(({ id, name }) => <span key={id}>{name}</span>)}
</div>;
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to generate jsx elements with event handler functions in iteration. Can I still use stateless component for that?

Comment: @Think-Twice Possibly yes, depending on what these handlers should do. Can you update the question with another example that shows that?

Answer (score 2):

the first method is correct. use the map function to iterate through the array.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];
        };
 }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>           
                {this.state.data.map((data,index)=>
                      <span key={data.id}>{data.name}</span>
                )}             
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the `map` inside the `return(...)` as map returns an array. It's cleaner and readable, something I personally strive for.

To add on to the answer, if the array `data` might change down the lane I'd go with creating a new stateless dump component:

```
const Spanner = props => { return <span key={ props.data.id }>{ props.data.name }</span> };

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello"}];
      return (
        <div>
          { 
            data.map( (item, ind) => {
              return (<Spanner key={item.id} data={item.name} />);
            })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This way we can use this Spanner Component as a common component shared among different component. And in case the `data` changes over time ( which most of the time, does) you can write a wrapper function to the Spanner component and call the new function wherever required.
`data=[{"id": "01", "name": "Hi", "userType": "Admin"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello", "userType": "Client"}];`

```
const UserWidget = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{ props.type }</h4>
      <Spanner key={ props.key } data={ props.name }/>
    </div>
  );
}
// now both the UserWidget and the Spanner Components can be used wherever required
// say a dashboard Component wants to use the UserWidget
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    let data = [{"id": "01", "name": "Hi", "userType": "Admin"}, {"id": "02", "name": "Hello", "userType": "Client"}];
      return (
        <div>
          { 
            data.map( (item, ind) => {
              return (<UserWidget type={ item.userType } key={item.id} data={item.name} />);
            })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This way you're not repeating yourself, and your App Component still has the expected behavior even if now the new `data` array has the new key `userType`.
Again this is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

The function `toSpan` can be reused.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [{id: `01`, name: `Hi`}, {id: `02`, name: `Hello`}]
    const toSpan = ({id, name}) => <span key={id}>{name}</span>
    return (
      <div>{data.map(toSpan)}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this for best understanding

```
 const data = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((data, dataIndex ) => <span key={dataIndex}>{data.name}</span>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here you can understand that the name belongs to with attribute.

Comment: index provided by map-method is not recommended to use as element key-value.