# How do I compose a better React list container component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small app fetching Movies. The component tree isn't very deep. I have state in App.js and it passes data to the Movies.js component. Now, Movies.js is just a container to render the ul list of Movies.

App.js passing data to Movies

```
<Movies
  modalData={this.state.modalData}
  toggleModal={this.openModal}
  isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
  closeModal={this.closeModal}
  items={this.state.data}
  getMovieInfo={this.getMovieInfo}
  addToFavorites={this.addToFavorites}
/>
```

Movies.js

```
const Movies = props => {
   const { items, getMovieInfo, addToFavorites, isOpen, toggleModal, closeModal, modalData } = props;
   const listItems = items.map((item, id) => (
     <Movie
       key={id}
       id={id}
       imdbID={item.imdbID}
       title={item.Title}
       poster={item.Poster}
       getMovieInfo={getMovieInfo}
       addToFavorites={addToFavorites}
       imdbid={item.imdbID}
       isOpen={isOpen}
       toggleModal={toggleModal}
       closeModal={closeModal}
       modalData={modalData}
     />
   ));
   return <ul id="movie-container">{listItems}</ul>;
 };
```

and finally Movies.js which is just an item that is rendered in the Movie  component. I tried using destructuring to keep the items prop for the Movies component because it needs that to map over and then ...props to Movie. I cant seem to make this work.

My app works fine but this is 'prop-drilling' and I think context may not be appropriate because this is not a deep tree. Higher Order Components, I don't understand yet. What can I do to make this better?

Movie.js

```
const Movie = props => {
  const {
    id,
    imdbID,
    title,
    poster,
    getMovieInfo,
    addToFavorites,
    isOpen,
    toggleModal,
    closeModal,
    modalData,
  } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <li className="movie" id={id}>
        <img srcSet={poster} alt={title} imdbid={imdbID} />
        <div className="movie-title">{title}</div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="button-small"
            onClick={toggleModal}
            imdbid={imdbID}
            title={title}
            id={id}>
            {' '}
            Info!!
          </button>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="button-small"
            onClick={addToFavorites}
            imdbid={imdbID}
            id={id}>
            {' '}
            Fav
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <Modal className="modal" selector="#modal-root" isOpen={isOpen} onClick={closeModal}>
        <div className="modal-1">
```

Comment: Code snippets allow for ReactJS examples.  Perhaps make a workable (or close enough) example as a snippet to demonstrate what is not working?

Comment: The app works fine I am asking how can I avoid the prop drilling. I am passing so many props through Movies.js, which only needs {items} and the rest go to Movie.js.

Comment: I feel your comment did a much better job at describing what your after than your entire question did.  Still, a working example using Stack Overflow's code snippet tool would be more ideal.

Comment: Regarding your comment, why not just slop it in one *movieProps* prop and pass that along, letting movieProp explode it into the necessary attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like:

```
const Movies = ({ items, ...other}) => {

<Movie {...other} />
```

Or,

```
const { items, ...other } = props
<Movie {...other} />
```

Your code in example:

```
const Movies = ({ items, ...other}) => {
   const listItems = items.map((item, id) => (
     <Movie
       key={id}
       id={id}
       {...other}
     />
   ));
   return <ul id="movie-container">{listItems}</ul>;
 };
```

---

Your update made me afraid. You need to destructure all otherwise it will go even longer like `id={other.id}`. If you feel it's good rather, then do:

```
const { items, ...other } = props
// now when you use other props like imdbid
imdbid={other.imdbid}
```

Comment: Why do we not need curly braces around ...other in <Movie />?

Comment: @KevinT. Ah, sorry my mistake. Updated.

Comment: Now it seems that with the destructuring, the Movie.js is not getting the data. I made an edit to show the Movie component.

Comment: I put {other."prop"} in all the props in Movie, and it renders, yet the id used in the callbacks is lost.

Comment: ah, that is id from items.map, not? just use `id={id}` for that.

Comment: fyi beware the `key={id}`. That will likely bite you in the future. If you can use something like `other.imdbid` that might be better (as long as that isn't empty).