# Visual Studio Code / React - Is there a possibility to display all possible props somewhere?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-props

I've got a question regarding `reactjs` and `visual studio code`.
I'm asking me, if there is somewhere a possibility to display all properties which can be passed to a component?

Actually I have a component `Exhibition` created, which should display an exhibition.
Sounds simple, but in detail there are several options to passed to an exhibition. 
It can be, that a individual `text` property is being passed, some exhibitions have only a `stand`, some a `stand` and a `hall` etc. 
The last thing I added, was a change in the exhibition `date`. Normally a exhibition is within one month, but now I had a exhibition, which will starts in march and ends in april. So I needed to add more properties again to the component. 
So it would be nice to have an overview when I call the component in code, to view all possible properties.

So a little bit similar to methods in `C#` where all parameter (options) are visible.

[image]

Here is the code of this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Language from './Language.data';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import externalLinkImage from '../images/externalLink.svg';

require('bootstrap');

class Exhibition extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.getMonthName = this.getMonthName.bind(this);
    }

    hoverOn() {
        document.getElementById(this.props.id).classList.add('opacity30');
        document.getElementById(this.props.id + "externalLinkImage").classList.add('displayBlock');
        document.getElementById(this.props.id + "externalLinkText").classList.add('displayBlock');
    }

    hoverOff() {
        document.getElementById(this.props.id).classList.remove('opacity30');
        document.getElementById(this.props.id + "externalLinkImage").classList.remove('displayBlock');
        document.getElementById(this.props.id + "externalLinkText").classList.remove('displayBlock');
    }

    getMonthName(monthNo) {
        let monthName;
        switch(monthNo)
        {
            case 1:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].january;
                break;
            case 2:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].february;
                break;
            case 3:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].march;
                break;
            case 4:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].april;
                break;
            case 5:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].may;
                break;
            case 6:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].june;
                break;
            case 7:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].july;
                break;
            case 8:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].august;
                break;
            case 9:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].september;
                break;
            case 10:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].october;
                break;
            case 11:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].november;
                break;
            case 12:
                monthName = Language[this.props.currentLanguage].december;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return monthName;
    }

    render() {
        let exhibitionImage = require('../images/exhibitions/' + this.props.exhibitionImage);
        const ExternalLink = styled.div`
            position:absolute;
            background-color:transparent;
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            left:50%;
            top:50%;
            margin-left:-15px;
            margin-top:-15px;
            background-image: url(${externalLinkImage});
            background-position:center;
            background-size:contain;
            display:none;
        `
        const ExternalLinkText = styled.div`
            position:absolute;
            left:50%;
            top:50%;
            width:200px;
            height:30px;
            margin-left:-100px;
            margin-top:15px;
            display:none;
            color:#000;
        `

        const ExhibitionImage = styled.img`
            padding:50px;
        `

        let standText = (this.props.standOwner === undefined) ? Language[this.props.currentLanguage].meetUsOnOurStand : Language[this.props.currentLanguage].meetUsAt + " " + this.props.standOwner + " " + Language[this.props.currentLanguage].stand;
        let monthName;
        let startMonthName;
        let endMonthName;
        if(this.props.startMonth != undefined && this.props.endMonth != undefined) {
            startMonthName = this.getMonthName(this.props.startMonth);
            endMonthName = this.getMonthName(this.props.endMonth);
        }
        else {
            monthName = this.getMonthName(this.props.month);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row" onMouseEnter={this.hoverOn.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.hoverOff.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <a href={this.props.linkUrl} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                            <ExhibitionImage id={this.props.id} src={exhibitionImage} className="img-fluid"></ExhibitionImage>
                            <ExternalLink id={this.props.id + "externalLinkImage"}></ExternalLink>
                            <ExternalLinkText id={this.props.id + "externalLinkText"}><small>{Language[this.props.currentLanguage].externalLink}</small></ExternalLinkText>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        {
                            this.props.text !== undefined && this.props.text.length > 0 &&
                            <div>
                                {this.props.text}
                            </div>
                        }
                        {
                            (this.props.text === undefined || this.props.text.length === 0) &&
                            <div>
                                {
                                    !this.props.location &&
                                    standText + " " + this.props.stand
                                }
                                {
                                    this.props.location && 
                                    Language[this.props.currentLanguage].meetUsIn + " " + this.props.location
                                }
                                {
                                    this.props.hall != undefined && this.props.hall != null && 
                                    ", " + Language[this.props.currentLanguage].hall + " " + this.props.hall
                                }
                                <br />
                                {
                                    this.props.startMonth && this.props.endMonth && 
                                    this.props.startDay + " " + startMonthName + " - " + this.props.endDay + " " + endMonthName + " " + this.props.year
                                } 
                                {
                                    this.props.month && 
                                    this.props.days + " " + monthName + " " + this.props.year
                                }
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Exhibition;
```

But maybe it's not a question about an overview, but of using a better way of handling / coding than I used... ;-)

Comment: Reading this post may help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271398/how-do-i-compose-a-better-react-list-container-component

Answer (score 0):

You can add this inside render function before you return the component.

```
console.log(this.props);
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not answering my question. I want to see which props are possible and not which props are given to a component, when the component is already rendered.

Comment: @dns_nx What do you mean by that? I mean what possible properties? coz we don't know what you actually pass when calling the component.

Comment: wait, I think your question is for the IDE you are using and not the actual output you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not answering my question. I want to see which props are possible and not which props are given to a component, when the component is already rendered.