# React mapping - Giving key prop when mapping over slug names

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to give a *key* prop to my *Tag* component, but I can't seem to give the right ID to my *Tag* component.

First, I am making a call to this (single image) endpoint:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`//derpibooru.org/${this.props.match.params.id}.json`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ singleImage: data }))
}
```

which serves this json file [here](https://derpibooru.org/44819.json) (for example). Here is an example image:

[image]

I then want to insert that ID inside of this *Tag* component in order to suppress the *key* prop warning from React.

```
        const tagList = this.state.singleImage.tags.split(', ').map( tag => {
                return (
                    <Link to={`/tags/${tag}`}>
                        <Tag key={???} tag={tag} />
                    </Link>
                )
            }
        )
```

However, here's the problem. I'm mapping over `[...].singleImage.tags` which are the tag *slugs*, but I don't receive the IDs. In the API, there is an endpoint of `//derpibooru.org/tags/{some_tag}.json` and at this (tags) endpoint, I can get the ID with `tag.id` and I attempted another fetch (inside of map) like this:

```
        const tagList = this.state.singleImage.tags.split(', ').map( tag => {
                fetch(`//derpibooru.org/tags/${tag}.json`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                  return (
                    <Link to={`/tags/${tag}`}>
                        <Tag key={data.tag.id} tag={tag} />
                    </Link>
                  )
                }
            }
        )
```

but then in this case, the `map` does not return.

I feel like this is the wrong approach since the single image endpoint *has* the `tag_ids`, but I just don't know how to put them inside my *Tag* component.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the slugs unique? If so they are fine to use. Otherwise, if the slug order is always the same, you could just use the index in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use index as key like

```
  const tagList = this.state.singleImage.tags.split(', ').map( (tag, index) => {
            return (
                <Link to={`/tags/${tag}`}>
                    <Tag key={'Key-'+index} tag={tag} />
                </Link>
            )
        }
    )
```

Comment: oh I had no idea you could use index like that in a map. that would have saved me a bunch of time! really good to know. i adopted your answer and saved the `tag_ids` in a state array and then used index to iterate through them like this `<Tag key={this.state.tagIDs[index]} tag={tag} />`. thanks for your answer i really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome :) index as a key is always second choice meaning when the data doesn’t have unique ids then we will depend on index for uniqueness like I mentioned in my answer. For more details take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176673/most-efficient-way-of-rendering-jsx-elements-when-iterating-on-array-of-data-in

Answer (score 1):

Because fetch(`//derpibooru.org/tags/${tag}.json`) it's async operation, and map work only with sync operations;

you can iterate your cycle inside `for` which inside `async await` function:

```
async function printFiles() {
    for (const tag of tags) {
        const res = await fetch(`//derpibooru.org/tags/${tag}.json`);
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: this is another good way to solve the problem with the tags endpoint, but I thought i could save the trouble from fetching again and using the `tag_ids` somehow just like Hemadri's answer. i'll consider this for the future. thank you Vadim.