# Good pratices for react functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm guessing, when my component start to grow big and has some complex logic in his functions, should I make a separated file for functions and handlers? Or its a better practice to maintain the component logic and render method in the same file?

Sorry if its not a good question, but this bother me. I hope to get some good tip. Thank you.

Comment: This may help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225812/2138752

Comment: You may benefit from redux methodology. It separates the logic from the component. It increases the structural complexity of the app, but reduces the file sizes.

Comment: Thank you guys, I ll read all the content and posts that everybody mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing a complex component, define at most **smallest** part for the component. This way, you'll have only required hooks and methods. So that you'll have clear vision on your way.

For eg.

**Bad**

- Face Component

**Good**

- Eye Component
- Mouth Component
- Nose Component
- Ear Component
- ... Component

You may also read the following docs:

- [components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
- [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

And most importantly:

- [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 0):

The React site provides a great overview about [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) that walks you through the thought process of building a searchable product data table using React.

I suggest starting there then looking through the whole **Main Concepts** section.

Building a scalable, well architected application takes experience. Not something you can glean from one stackoverflow question. Best of luck!