# How to get "name" attribute of a specific mapped file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

Here is the embedded JSX code:

```
<Col>
  <h2> Found Files </h2>
  {this.state.foundFiles.map(files => (
   <div className = "file-box-search" key={files}>
     <input type = "checkbox" name = {files.id}></input> 
     <p className = ""> <a href = {files.click}> {files.file} </a> </p>
     <p> {files.description}</p>
   </div>
  ))}
 </Col>
```

Just for clarity on what's going on here:

1. this.state.foundFiles is an array object that holds the files I am mapping through, which values such as id and file. An example looks like this:

   ```
   {
     file: 'lesson 1',
     id: '1qupvie1LqNdLj-1TZNu3x6-4bT411C4F2YYGSfpc7yk',
     description: undefined,
     type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
     properties: { subject: 'math', grade: 'pre-k' },
     parents: [ '1kAzxwEgX5ftI-Sa4nUDK1Y5rJOSJ6VrU' ]
   },
   ```
2. The .map() loops through this array and gives several different formatted divs dependent on the values of each  file in the array.

Within this .map() method there is a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, I want to invoke a function that can use the name attribute of that specific checkbox within the map method. I can't just target by id, because then every element within the method would have the same exact id.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Isn't each file id unique? Assuming they are this seems like a non-problem

Comment: Yes and no. Because you can't set a unique file id for every single value that is returned from the map. Within the map method here, say I gave the p element an id of "fileD". If this map were only returning one value with these parameters, that would be fine, and any outside function would know what I mean if I say "fileD". Since it is returning several different objects though, each one is going to have an id of "fileD", which means I can't target a specific returned result. For this problem, I am trying to get the name attribute from the checkbox of a specific returned result. @charlietfl

Comment: I mean the values like the one shown like `1qupvie1LqNdLj-1TZNu3x6-4bT411C4F2YYGSfpc7yk` ...using that and `Array#find()` you can get the object in array that has that `id`. Pass that into your onChange event handler call

Comment: Or since you use it as name also search array using `event.target.name` to match `id` in objects

Comment: Gotcha. I'm going to try to put that together.

Answer (score 0):

[That's where](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220453/2138752) I suggest to define some constant value with the index:

```
.map((files, index) => {
  // ${`checkbox-${index}-${files.id}`}
```

Comment: So how would I go about using that in this context? Could you show me an example where you are using the value of name in an outside function?